# How do i pass a big int while creating the sequence in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a sequence

`CREATE SEQUENCE seq_id MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NO CYCLE`

It throws an ERROR:  value "9999999999999999999999999999" is out of range for type bigint. I am trying to convert oracle queries to postgreSQL.

Comment: Use `NO MAXVALUE`

Answer (score 0):

An eight-byte integer cannot contain this number, but then you don't need such a big number anyway.

Use

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_id CACHE 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually just use bigserial when creating a table.

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  seq_column bigserial,
  some_column text,
)
```

This creates a sequence automatically for you.
See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

Also possible:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq AS bigint;
```